# How to wait until HTML file loads?

Tags: asynchronous

In a page I am working on I replace the HTML code in a DIV with different HTML, then using Javascript I insert additional HTML into a DIV the new code using innerHTML.

If that is confusing, the original HTML contained a form, the HTML that replaced it contains the response to the form's *Submit*, and the code I want to insert is the information from the form.

This seemed to work as long as I had *alert* code in the script, which I use to check the progress as I debug this. Once I removed the all of *alert* lines the insert would fail. I figure it has to do something with the asynchronous nature of page rendering, so I think I need to find a way to make sure the new HTML code has loaded before I try writing to the DIV it contains.

In the code below the script fails at *show_member_info* unless I uncomment the preceding *alert* line.

```js
function handle_join(X)
{
    do_trace('handle_update');  
    get_member_info();
    send_emails(X);
    
    do_trace('clear content');  
    document.getElementById("members_content").innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById("members_image").innerHTML='';
    
    do_trace('load content');   
    Load_HTML('members/joinConf.html','members_content');

//  alert('show_member_info');  
    show_member_info();
    show_trace();
}
```

How do I determine when the new HTML has loaded and is ready to be manipulated?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit dry, but from what i can understand the problem is that you are not awaiting `Load_HTML` and that's causing some issue with `show_member_info`.

Comment: I figure that's it. I don't want to use a timed wait. It would be unreliable as wait needed times will vary. I am considering a whole new approach but I sure would like to solve this puzzle.

Comment: You just need to make the Load_HTML function async and then put await in front of it when calling it and also make handle_join async, so that it waits for it to be complete then does the other functions under it.